# One plot with different density functions in different regions?

Tags: plotting, visualization

As you can see in the following photo, there are 4 regions in the photo. Each photo has a different density function $T_i$.

[image]

For ①  $T_1=223+380 x+385y$

For ②  $T_2=446+1080x+450y$

For ③  $T_3=108+4460x+450y;$

For ④  $T_4=198+4010x$

Now I want to plot the density plot of the entire image?

The method I am using is to merge $T_i$ to one $T$ with bool operator. Here is the code:

```
T1=223+380 x+385y;
T2=446+1080x+450y;
T3=108+4460x+450y;
T4=198+4010x;

DensityPlot[
    T1*Boole[x>=0&&y<=0.1&&(x-y<=0)]+
    T2*Boole[x<=0.10&&y>=0&&(x-y>=0)]+
    T3*Boole[x>=0.1&&y>=0&&(x+y<0.2)]+
    T4*Boole[x<=0.2&&y<=0.1&&x+y>=0.2],{x,0,0.2},
    {y,0,0.1},
    PlotPoints->100,AspectRatio->1/2,ImageSize->Medium]
```

The result is

[image]

I am a Mathematica newbie and I confirm there is better code for this problem. I've tried PlotRange & RegionFunction but had no idea how to do.

Could you please help me with more elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically equivalent but more elegant than your solution:

```
f1[x_, y_] := 223 + 380 x + 385 y;
f2[x_, y_] := 446 + 1080 x + 450 y;
f3[x_, y_] := 108 + 4460 x + 450 y;
f4[x_, y_] := 198 + 4010 x;

DensityPlot[
 Which[
     y > x, f1[x, y],
     y < x < .1, f2[x, y],
    .1 < x < .2 - y, f3[x, y],
     y > .2 - x, f4[x, y]],
 {x, 0, .2}, {y, 0, .1},
 PlotLegends ->Automatic,
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think using `Which` is much better.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach: (1) Construct a list of functions (`functions`) from your `{T1, ..., T4}`, (2) make a boolean list of from your conditions (`boole`), (3) use `Dot[boole, Through  @ functions[x,y]]` as the first argument  of `DensityPlot`:

```
functions = Function[{x, y}, #] & /@ {T1, T2, T3, T4};
boole = Boole @ {y > x, y < x < .1, .1 < x < .2 - y, y > .2 - x};

DensityPlot[boole.Through[functions[x, y]],
   {x, 0, .2}, {y, 0, .1},
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Add the option `ExclusionsStyle -> Red` to emphasize the region boundaries:

[image]

Comment: Thank for your solution! I don't know about `Through` and I am going to check it in the help.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) instead of `Which`, `Boole`, etc. because `Piecewise` has better support in mathematical operations.

```
T1 = 223 + 380 x + 385 y;
T2 = 446 + 1080 x + 450 y;
T3 = 108 + 4460 x + 450 y;
T4 = 198 + 4010 x;

P = DensityPlot[
  Piecewise[{{T1, x >= 0 && y <= 0.1 && (x - y <= 0)},
             {T2, x <= 0.10 && y >= 0 && (x - y >= 0)},
             {T3, x >= 0.1 && y >= 0 && (x + y < 0.2)},
             {T4, x <= 0.2 && y <= 0.1 && x + y >= 0.2}}],
    {x, 0, 0.2}, {y, 0, 0.1},
    PlotPoints -> 100, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> Medium, 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, `Piecewise` is indeed better. I always use it in two variables problem, your solution is enlightening.